# Which is an efficient way to check if a character is alphabetic or not?

Tags: java

What could be an efficient way to check a character is alphabet or not?
Using

`Character.isLetter(ch)`

(or)

```
if( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
```

Comment: Why don't you go with what's more readable?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about such small performance issues. I'd focus more on readability

Comment: What about Unicode?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "alphabetic".  Second way is _possibly_ slightly more "efficient" if by "alphabetic" you mean "any uppercase or lowercase letter of the basic Latin alphabet as used in English (and also some other languages)".  If an "alphabetic" character could be _any_ "letter" of _any_ Unicode-supported script, then the second way is just plain wrong, and the first is probably at least as efficient, and probably more likely to be correct,  as anything you or I would write for ourselves.

Comment: Well, that's another thing that needs to be clear: what is a 'character' in the context of this question?  If it's ```char``` in Java then it's  a16-bit Unicode codepoint.  You could support EBCDIC as a CharacterSet, but a sequence of chars would be converted into a sequence of bytes as part of the conversion to EBCDIC.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for A-Z a-z does not check all alphabetic characters. so the question seems moot.

Character.isAlphabetic(c) tests whether c is alphabetic.

Character.isLetter(c) tests whether c is a letter.

The two are not equivalent so you should be clear on the question you're trying to answer.  The difference is that there are number-indications that are alphabetic but not letters; think Roman numerals.  [Link to list.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
//function to check whether given character is an alphabet or not
 function check(n){   
var a=(+n);   //If unary operator operates on a string then we get NaN.
    if(isNaN(a)){          //Checking if a is NaN
        console.log("This is a alphabet")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Is a number")
    }

    }
    check(12)
    check("a");
```